# Gulp: load order from a file to concat

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

Our application concats a list of ~100 HTML files in some specific order into one single file. The order information should be extracted from a special html file `order.html`. So the process should be:

1. Use cheerio (or other plugin) to extract order information from `order.html`
2. For each file on the extracted `order` list, process it using `cheerio` (or other plugin)
3. Concat all processed files according to the `order` list, save to `output.html`.

I have tried `gulp-order`, which simply orders by a hardcoded list. But we need a dynamic order list. How to make it?

Comment: Just curious.. would this be possible with https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sort ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I just solved this problem by storing the order information in some temp file, and then read from this file to load the dependencies. This solution works. But it is not so nice, as it introduces some temp storage.